# Удаление элементов на сайте при помощи расширения chrome

Tags: html, jquery, chrome-extension

Необходимо при помощи расширения chrome удалить некоторые элементы с сайта.

Схема работы:

1. Получение структуры сайта.
2. Поиск нужных элементов.
3. Удаление этих элементов, когда они загружаются сайтом.
   *Догадываюсь, что нужно использовать Jquery и функцию .remove, но стоит вопрос получения элементов с сайта и их следующего удаления.*

P.S. Это мой первый вопрос на StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Прописываем в манифесте правила в блоке content_scripts > js(для сайта), matches (адрес сайта) [подробнее](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), читайте документацию.

```
"content_scripts":[
    {
      "js":[
          "build/jquery-1.11.3.min.js",
          "src/remove.js"
      ],
      "matches":[
        "https://www.google.ru/*"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ]
```

Далее пишем в remove.js

```
(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function(){

        console.log("delet");
        $('.g .rc .r a').remove();

    });
}(jQuery));
```